# are there center-allocation deque or vector in STL implementations?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, deque

I was reading about `deque`s vs `vector`s, and came across its [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue), which says one of the three possible implementations of `deque` using dynamic arrays is:

> Allocating deque contents from the center of the underlying array, and
>   resizing the underlying array when either end is reached. This
>   approach may require more frequent resizings and waste more space,
>   particularly when elements are only inserted at one end.

I was wondering if there are any STL (or STL-style) implementations that actually use this center-allocation strategy?

I am asking because this strategy looks rather appealing as it involves only one underlying array, and thus removes the memory dis-contiguity issue, which is probably the only major issue `deque` has when compared to `vector`. If I understand it right, this could well be a replacement for `std::vector` that allows O(1) `pop_front` (amortized) or a replacement for `deque` with memory-contiguity guarantees. I assume that this is at the cost of doubling the buffering space of a `std::vector`, which is not a major concern for my use cases.

Also, is it true that insertion/deletion in the middle of such a container would take half the time of `std::vector` on average?

---

UPDATE:

As @Lightness Races in Orbit pointed out, such a implementation will not be used under current standards because no one can benefit from the upsides per contract with STL and everyone will suffer from the downsides. A further question I have regarding the downsides is this:

Is it possible to implement a **new** `vector` or `deque` like container (say `bivector`) such that in addition to the functionality/operators of `std::vector`,

1) provides (amortized) constant time `push_front()` and `pop_front()` operations and

2) guarantees memory contiguity but not iterator validity after growing sizes?

I imagine with one array behind the scene, a lot of the indirection/performance issues on `deque` would go away.

Comment: Wouldn't you still need to move the contents once you hit the ends of the array in order to maintain contiguity?

Comment: Maybe we can just re-allocate memory as `std::vector` does when its right end is reached. I think the cost of re-allcation when averaged with non-breaching inserts is amortized O(1) as with `vector`. I imagine we can do the `vector` trick "on both ends".

Answer (score 3):

No Standard Library (not "STL") implementation is going to bother with this, because it has the downsides you mention, and the upsides are not part of the requirement for `std::deque`.

Those requirements are carefully constructed, right from algorithmic complexity for various operations, through to iterator invalidation rules. There is no benefit in implementing a container in such a way that nobody can rely on that implementation's upsides.

Could the C++ committee introduce a new container in a future standard with a different name and with different constraints, which vendors could implement as you describe? Yes, they could.

Comment: *"There is no benefit in implementing a container in such a way that nobody can rely on that implementation's upsides."* - You [can't really rely on the implementation upsides anyway](http://blog.hostilefork.com/locality-locality-locality/).  :-/

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you lack that container.  Start with something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class bi_vec {
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> raw;
  std::size_t first = 0;
  std::size_t last = 0;
  std::size_t capacity = 0;
  char* raw_get( std::size_t index ) {
    return &raw[index*sizeof(T)];
  }
  char const* raw_get( std::size_t index ) const {
    return &raw[index*sizeof(T)];
  }
  T& get( std::size_t index ) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(raw_get(index));
  }
  T const& get( std::size_t index ) const {
    return *reinterpret_cast<T const *>(raw_get(index));
  }
  char* raw_before() {
    if (first < 1)
      grow();
    --first;
    return raw_get(first);
  }
  char* raw_after() {
    if (last+1 >= capacity)
      grow();
    ++last;
    return raw_get(last-1);
  }
  void grow() {
    std::vector new_capacity = (capacity+1)*2;
    std::size_t new_first = (new_capacity - (last-first)) / 2;
    std::size_t new_last = new_capacity - new_first;
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> new_buff( new char[new_capacity*sizeof(T)] );
    T* b = &get(0);
    T* e = &get(last-first);
    std::move( b, e, reinterpret_cast<T*>( &new_buff[new_first*sizeof(T)] ) );
    std::swap( buff, raw );
    std::swap( new_capacity, capacity );
    std::swap( new_first, first );
    std::swap( new_last, last );
    for (T* it = b; it != e; ++it) {
      it->~T();
    }
  }
public:
  T& operator[]( std::size_t index ) { return get(index); }
  T const& operator[]( std::size_t index ) const { return get(index); }
  template<class... Us>
  void emplace_back( Us&&...us ) {
    char* a = raw_after();
    new (a) T( std::forward<Us>(us) );
  }
  template<class... Us>
  void emplace_front( Us&&...us ) {
    char* a = raw_before();
    new (a) T( std::forward<Us>(us) );
  }
  ~bi_vec() {
    for( std::size_t i = 0; i != last-first; ++i ) {
      get(i).~T();
    }
  }
};
```

and add iterators (I'd be tempted to use `boost` iterator helpers, or raw pointers to start) and whatever interfaces you need.  Note that the above needs work to ensure it remains exception safe.

Comment: Here's what I have so far: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43d045883dc4666e  Can be fully instantated as `bi_vec<int>` though no other compilation much less testing has been done.  Realistically I kept it rather simple, so any bugs should be few (saying nothing of severity)

Comment: @Mooing Duck, Thanks a lot! How long did it take you to program all this. Your code compiled OK on my computer, with gcc-4.8.1 on TDM-MinGW64. However, I get some errors when I instantiate a variable like `bi_vec<int> a;`

Comment: About 3 hours. Apparently explicit instantiation doesn't do as much as I'd expected. It should now be instantiatable as a variable: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e32536b2d6c2561  Also added missing constructors

Comment: @TingL: There, I figured out why it wasn't instantiating fully, and added a ton of tests.  It should be vaguely passable now: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac49da47af600c15

Comment: @MooingDuck that is why I suggested using `T*` as an iterator in a first pass.  Btw, why does your iterator have both a `T*` and an index, why not just a `T*`?

Comment: @Yakk: Check again, the iterator _is_ a `T*`, it's not even a class.  The `reference_iterator` is a separate helper.  Its usage is shown most clearly here:  `bi_vec(size_type n) :<snip> {inplacefactory f; _insert(first, make_ref_iter(f,0), make_ref_iter(f, n));}`

Comment: @MooingDuck ah, I would have called it `immobile_iterator` and have it take a `T*` in the constructor, or have it take an arbitrary iterator and just refuse to move it.  ;)